# Keep popup in the same position on 100% and 80% zoom levels on browser

Tags: css

I have a popup that is moving slightly at different zoom levels on the browser. I would like it to be at the same spot irrespective of whether the user is on 100% zoom or 80% zoom.

Here is how it currently looks at 100% zoom

[image: 100% Zoom]

Here is how it looks at 80% zoom

[image: 80% Zoom]

The popup is moving further away from the *Retirement Projection* text on the right

Here is my code for the popup

```
.savings-tip {
  background-color: #1a202c;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-top: 445px;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 515px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 0%;
}
```

Here is a stackblitz example of the basic parent(popup-wrap) and popup

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhpbg3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You need to relatively position the parent of this prop up, and the add top/bottom and right/left by keeping the popup absolute, as per the requirement this way it will not move away from its position even if you have reduced/increased the zoom. If you are able to share the code, I can help you with it.

Comment: A mere CSS snippet is not enough to reproduce problems like this. It gives us no clue, what the structural relation is between this popup element, and the _Retirement Projection_ text (if any useful one exists to begin with.) Please provide a _proper_ [mre] when you are asking for help in cases like this.

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I made a stackblitz example. It's just got the basics of what I have

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhpbg3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: It's still not sufficient, it doesn't have the required code, where I can hover on certain element to encounter the actual issue.

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I added the text block, when you zoom out the popup block moves further away from the text on the right

Comment: The code is kind of confusing though, but I'll try to explain you what needs to be done. Firstly you need to move the popup code inside the div on which you are going to hover or click. Then define the that parent div (not the pop up div) with position relative. As your parent div is relative and the pop block which is immediate child is already set to absolute, so it will become relative to your parent not to the root element. Now set the top/bottom and left/right properties. This is the way you need to solve the problem.
It is important to move the pop up block inside the relative div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through this pen, you'll get better understanding on this:

https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/ZEOmYLP

so basically I created this parent div with menu class and added a span where you can hover your mouse and by default popup will be hidden.

```html
<div class="menu">
    <span>Hover over me (positioned relatively)</span>
    <div class="popup">
        the content with absolute positioning
    </div>
</div>
```

I kept the parent div with class menu relative and the div with class popup is set to absolute. This way the popup will never leave its position, in a nutshell it will always stick to the span(visually) or you can say the parent div (technically).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
    position: relative;
}

.menu:hover > .popup{
    display: block;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 110%;
    width: 200px
}
```